# laravel accessing Session in Model

Tags: php, laravel, session, model-view-controller, model

I am using larave-7. Is it possible to access session value in model?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use Session;
class Permissions extends Model {
function has_permission($menu_controller){
$permission_type = Session::get('permission_type');
    
$result = DB::table('admin_permission')->where('admin_type_id',$permission_type)- >where('apps_menu_id',0)->get();
```

Here I am not getting any result from the session.How can I get session value to do my query successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the session content?

```
$data = $request->session()->all();
```

Did you put permission type in session?

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

Comment: yes, everything is used but the session is not working

Comment: maybe missing middleware \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

Comment: I have  Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, this one already added.should I add your one too? @snail

Comment: add it in app -> Http -> Kernel.php